# SQL/SSRS Nested Query where, IN and AND

Tags: ssrs-2012

I want to get events in one the 3 types and for 1 type only where quantity is greater than 0. However, quantity is 0 for other two types and I want them as well in output.

Query I am using - WHERE
({PortfolioEvent.EventType} IN ("Call","Mature", "Sell")) OR (({PortfolioEvent.EventType}  == "Sell" AND QtyAmount >=1))

I want transactions at call and mature level in output regardless of quantity of 0.

Thanks

Comment: Is this not working? Your WHERE clause looks like it should work - I don't know what you're using that uses braces {}, double quotes, and double equals ==.

Comment: Thanks Hannover Fist. I little modified the code as - WHERE ({PortfolioEvent.EventType} IN ("Call","Mature", QtyAmount <>0)) OR (({PortfolioEvent.EventType} == "Sell" AND QtyAmount >=1)) but getting an error for <> sign.